# Classic ASP getPathName and getName Error

Tags: asp-classic

I usually developed website using PHP. But now i have to using ASP Classic because my client already have a website then i have to maintenance the website. i already move all of the website to my new hosting. But there is error on this code :

`cPath=getPathName(Server.mappath(Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")))`

The error message is :

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
>
> Type mismatch: 'getPathName'

Some error display when call `getName` code.

Please help me what should i do.

Comment: Can you add a little bit more, for example where you declare cPath. - Type mismatch is a general error that happens when you try to stuff one type of value into a variable of another type.

Comment: @Robuust the reason for Type Mismatch here is that `getPathName` was created by VBScript automatically but given the type Empty. Since he was trying to use it as a function, it resulted in type mismatch. The wonders of scripting language!

Answer (score 1):

Classic ASP or VBScript do not have equivalent to the PHP `getPathName()` and `getName()` functions as far as I can tell.

I wasn't able to understand what's the meaning of `getPathName()` when it's given a string and actually I don't think it exists, so just have:

```
cPath = Server.MapPath(Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO"))
```

And the variable will contain the full physical path to the currently executing ASP file.

As for `getName()` you can write custom function:

```vbs
Function GetOnlyName(filePath)
    Dim slashIndex
    slashIndex = InStrRev(filePath, "\")
    If slashIndex<1 Then
        slashIndex = InStrRev(filePath, "/")
    End If
    If slashIndex>0 Then
        ExtractFileName = Mid(filePath, slashIndex + 1, Len(filePath) - slashIndex + 1)
    Else  
        ExtractFileName = filePath
    End If
End Function
```

Then use it like this:

```
cName = GetOnlyName(Server.MapPath(Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")))
```

And the variable will contain only the name of the ASP file.

For the record, to avoid confusing Type Mismatch errors, **always** put this on top of your scripts:

```
Option Explicit
```

Then always declare all your variable using `Dim` statement, like in the function above. Having this, trying to use `getPathName` would give "variable undefined" error which is much more meaningful.